# What size breaker will I need for my workshop subpanel, wire, and electrical conduit to feed it through?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, conduit

Adding a subpanel to my workshop, it's less than 20' away, it's for 2 (240V Plugs), 5(120 V Plugs), and a couple of LED fixtures, nothing more.

Comment: "what size breaker" leads immediately to "what are you plugging in to those outlets, and how much of it will get used at once?" Workshops are highly variable depending what sort of work you are doing. 5 hp planer and a 3-hp dust collector? Chopsaw and a shop vac? You work in ceramics and are running an electric kiln? Very different capacities needed. Basment or garage location? GFCI required, etc..

Comment: What is the amperage expected for the plugs?  Breakers and wire size go by amps.

Comment: *i.e.* for plugs, 240V plugs/receptacles are commonly available in 15, 20, 30, 50 and 60 Amp flavors. 120V are available in 15, 20, 30 and 50A flavors, though we'll tend to assume 15 or 20 if not otherwise specified for those, as the "common" ones. On the 240V side, there really isn't a default "common" size.

Comment: What are you plugging into those outlets?